# Angularjs ng-repeat counting filtered items with AND condition

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using checkboxes to filter a resultset from a json file. It's working fine, but I would like to have the count (from the filtered resultset only) appearing next to each filter. I've tried a few ways to do this but I can only end up getting the length of the result itself or the json output.

I have a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJyNDGfi7sB478J52Lpl?p=preview)

```
( {{ data.list|filter:itemFilter[option.name].count }} )
```

Another [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJyNDGfi7sB478J52Lpl?p=preview)

Any help is appreciated.

Jimi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{{ ((data.list | filter:itemFilter)|filter:option.name).length }}
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5tPeluGJa6rELeAaJt4?p=preview)

Comment: I tried that way, it just gives the length of the result set for each filter. The part that I'm struggling with is to make the all individual. i.e if I tick 'has fodhall' and then 'has bakery','has kitchen' should be 0 as it does not have a value in the current filtered result set. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jimi no, sorry, could you please give me an example? I thought that the number in the parenthesis was supposed to be the number of items that have that property... There are 2 items that 'have chicken', therefore 2... And 2 that 'have bakery', that's why the other 2... Could you please give me an example of what you want? Thanks!

Comment: I added another plunk to (hopefully) illustrate. I've added another filter condition. When I tick 'has food hall ( 1 )' & 'has bakery ( 1 )' because the other 'has kitchen ( 1 )' does not have either of those values it should be 'has kitchen ( 0 )'. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @Jimi I've updated my answer, please check the current plunker, thanks! And check this one too: http://plnkr.co/edit/gY6v7kRnCuGn3RPpzZW0?p=preview